# How to prevent Wordpress built-in “browse link” entering the data in wp-editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, meta-boxes

Working with Wordpress Meta Box and I used the code of [Dale Sattler](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12344/dale-sattler) from this [How can I use the built in Wordpress “browse link” functionality?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127088/how-can-i-use-the-built-in-wordpress-browse-link-functionality) to create a custom field with wp browse link it works fine, but it inserted the data in wp-editor too.

I try to prevent the default event using code here [Use WordPress link insert dialog in metabox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812929/use-wordpress-link-insert-dialog-in-metabox) but doesn't work, I try that code too but it have a bug too.

here is my code

```
var _link_sideload = false; //used to track whether or not the link dialogue actually existed on this page, ie was wp_editor invoked.
var link_btn = (function($){
    'use strict';
    var _link_sideload = false; //used to track whether or not the link dialogue actually existed on this page, ie was wp_editor invoked.
    var input_field = '';

    /* PRIVATE METHODS
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    //add event listeners

    function _init() {
        $('body').on('click', '.link-btn', function(event) {
            _addLinkListeners();
            _link_sideload = false;

            input_field = $(this).attr('href');
            var link_val_container = $(input_field);

            if ( typeof wpActiveEditor != 'undefined') {
                wpLink.open();
                wpLink.textarea = $(link_val_container);
            } else {
                window.wpActiveEditor = true;
                _link_sideload = true;
                wpLink.open();
                wpLink.textarea = $(link_val_container);
            }
            return false;
        });

    }

    /* LINK EDITOR EVENT HACKS
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    function _addLinkListeners() {
        $('body').on('click', '#wp-link-submit', function(event) {
            var linkAtts = wpLink.getAttrs();
            console.log(linkAtts);
            var link_val_container = $(input_field);
            link_val_container.val(linkAtts.href);
            _removeLinkListeners();
            return false;
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#wp-link-cancel', function(event) {
            _removeLinkListeners();
            return false;
        });
    }

    function _removeLinkListeners() {
        if(_link_sideload){
            if ( typeof wpActiveEditor != 'undefined') {
                wpActiveEditor = undefined;
            }
        }

        wpLink.close();
        wpLink.textarea = $('html');//focus on document

        $('body').off('click', '#wp-link-submit');
        $('body').off('click', '#wp-link-cancel');
    }

    /* PUBLIC ACCESSOR METHODS
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    return {
        init:       _init,
    };

})(jQuery);
```

please help, please ....

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found a way to remove the link from the content. In your submit event you need to add:

```
$('body').on('click', '#wp-link-submit', function(event) {
    var linkAtts = wpLink.getAttrs();
    var link_val_container = $(input_field);
    link_val_container.val(linkAtts.href);

    var $frame = $('#content_ifr'),
    $added_links = $frame.contents().find("a[data-mce-href]");

    $added_links.each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href') === linkAtts.href) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });

    _removeLinkListeners();
    return false;
});
```

`$('#content_ifr')` is the iframe that loads tinymce editor with content inside. Since the `iframe` is loaded from the same domain you can mess around it (luckily). So you just go through its contents and you're looking for anchors that have data attribute called `mce-href`, and if the link that you've just added has the href value as the one you've added it removes them.

I re did this part of the code because I've noticed that all the links in my content had this attribute so you cannot just remove all anchors that have 
`data-mce-href` attribute because that would remove all of them. And you only want to remove those you've added in your metabox.

This did the trick for me :)